# CreateProcess succeeds but produces error 1812 (The specified image file did not contain a resource section)

Tags: delphi, winapi

Following code

```
function Run(exePath, cmdLine, currDir: string): Boolean;
var
  si: TStartupInfo;
  pinf: TProcessInformation;
  hStdOut: THandle;
  sa: TSecurityAttributes;
  lastErr: LongWord;
begin
  sa.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
  sa.bInheritHandle := True;
  sa.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;

  si := default(TStartupInfo);
  si.cb := SizeOf(si);
  si.dwFlags    := si.dwFlags; // or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

  SetLastError(0);
  Result := Createprocess(PWideChar(exePath), PWideChar(cmdLine), nil, nil,
    True, 0 {CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE}, nil, PWideChar(currDir), si, pinf);
  if Result then begin
    WaitForSingleObject(pinf.hProcess, INFINITE);
    lastErr := GetLastError(); // Here error 1812
    if lastErr <> 0 then ShowError(lastErr);
    CloseHandle(pinf.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pinf.hThread);
  end
  else begin
    lastErr := GetLastError();
    if lastErr <> 0 then ShowError(lastErr);
  end;
end;
```

produces error 1812 (The specified image file did not contain a resource section) on various executables (git, cgrc, dcc32).

What is it and how to eliminate it?

P.S. Here is an extracted piece of code I was wondering about:

```
SetLastError(0);
ShowError(GetLastError()); // Here the error code is 0
Result := Createprocess(PWideChar(exePath), PWideChar(cmdLine), nil, nil, False, 0, nil, PWideChar(currDir), si, pinf);
ShowError(GetLastError()); // Here error 1812
```

My logic was as follows: If before of `CreateProcess` call the last error code is 0, and after is not 0, then it is definitely `CreateProcess` who set the value. And why to set an error code if no error happened?

This logic seems to be false and even if the function succeeds, last error code can be set.

Comment: Your use of `GetLastError()` is wrong. You are calling it after the call to `WaitForSingleObject` but without checking if the function call was successful. So what `GetLastError()` returns in this case is totally irrelevant. It could even be the last error of an API call that failed some time before your `Run` function, because a successful function call does not mean that the last error will be set to zero. Some API may do that, but it is not required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error handling code is broken. Your function should look like this:

```
function Run(exePath, cmdLine, currDir: string): Boolean;
var
  si: TStartupInfo;
  pinf: TProcessInformation;
  hStdOut: THandle;
  sa: TSecurityAttributes;
  waitResult: DWORD;
  lastErr: LongWord;
begin
  sa.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
  sa.bInheritHandle := True;
  sa.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;

  si := default(TStartupInfo);
  si.cb := SizeOf(si);
  si.dwFlags    := si.dwFlags; // or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

  UniqueString(cmdLine);
  Result := CreateProcess(PWideChar(exePath), PWideChar(cmdLine), nil, nil,
    True, 0 {CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE}, nil, PWideChar(currDir), si, pinf);
  if Result then begin
    waitResult := WaitForSingleObject(pinf.hProcess, INFINITE);
    if waitResult = WAIT_FAILED then begin
      lastErr := GetLastError();
      if lastErr <> 0 then ShowError(lastErr);
    end else begin
      Assert(waitResult = WAIT_OBJECT_0);
    end;
    CloseHandle(pinf.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pinf.hThread);
  end
  else begin
    lastErr := GetLastError();
    if lastErr <> 0 then ShowError(lastErr);
  end;
end;
```

Notes:

- The second argument to `CreateProcess` must be a writeable string. Hence the call to `UniqueString`.
- As documented in `WaitForSingleObject`, failure is indicated by the return value. You should only call `GetLastError` in case the return value indicates failure.
- I removed the call to `SetLastError(0)` which is needless.
- If `ShowError` raises exceptions then this function will leak handles.

I expect that what was happening was that `CreateProcess` was succeeding, but not setting the last error to zero, which it has no obligation to do. Remember that success or failure is indicated by the return value, not the error code. Then `WaitForSingleObject` was also succeeding, and not setting the error code to zero, again which it has no obligation to do. Or perhaps it was `WaitForSingleObject` that was setting the error code to a non-zero value. In any case, which function did this is moot. Once you fix the error checking code, you won't ever have cause to look at this meaningless error code.

Finally, are you quite sure that you want the child process to inherit handles?

Comment: Well, this question isn't about your code, it's about the code in the question. But from what you describe, it sounds like the exact same problem. Calling `GetLastError` when its value is not defined.